# C++ ofstream can't open file from variable name (not even after using c_str())

Tags: c++, c++11, filestream

In my code I am trying to create a file and write to it:

```
std::ofstream saveFile("file.txt");
ofstream << "test" << endl;
```

Works perfectly!
But,

```
std::string fileName = "file.txt"
std::ofstream saveFile(filename.c_str());
ofstream << "test" << endl;
```

I've tried with and without c_str(), with no luck. There are no errors. But ofstream.good() returns false.

Comment: BTW: If you solved your own problem, that's what self-answers are for. Don't put them into the question!

Answer (score 1):

It should work. But do you really post the right code?

At least your code has several obvious syntax errors:

```
std::string fileName = "file.txt"; // no semicolon
std::ofstream saveFile(fileName.c_str()); // 'fileName' rather than 'filename'
saveFile << "test" << endl; // don't redirect "test" to std::ofstream
// std::ofstream is a class rather than an instance
```

Please refer to [fstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Turns out the problem was with an invalid character being passed into the string for the file name. In my case, it was the backspace character.